# custom google search autocomplete

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, google-search

Устанавливаю `<gcse:search data-enableAutoComplete="true"></gcse:search>`, но автозаполнение се равно не работает. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А вы javascript подключили ?

Comment: @Arsen конечно!

Comment: думаю у вас проблемы с Custom Search engine ID. В примере всё работает http://jsfiddle.net/gh/gist/library/pure/6164084/

Comment: Автокомплит нормально работает, хотя только для латиницы, насколько помню это связано с настройками (для кирилицы)

Comment: @Arsen Custom Search engine ID по идее работает, ибо просто поиск работает нормально, может нужна индексация какая-то специальная?